# How to wait for user response on Meteor AutoForm submission?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, sweetalert

I am using Meteor and Aldeed's Autoform. I want to check that the user is certain before submission takes place. I have tried many things but when I press the button, the form submits anyway. Here's what I have now, which produces a modal nicely (with SweetAlert) even though submission occurs in the background anyway:

```
AutoForm.hooks({
    createEventForm: {
        before: function() {
            this.event.preventDefault();
        },
        beginSubmit: function() {
            this.event.preventDefault();
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                closeOnConfirm: true },
                function(){
                swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success"); });
        },
```

How can I make the form wait for the user to confirm or cancel the operation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `beginSubmit` is called at the beginning of the form submission. As the [documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks) states, it can be used to disable/enable buttons or showing a wait message when submitting longer requests. If you want to display a confirmation message and submit the form depending on the user's decision, you need to use the `before` hook.

For example:

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  createEventForm: hooksObject
});

var hooksObject = {
  before: {
    insert: function(doc) {
      var self = this;
      swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: true
      }, function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
          /* Submit form: */
          self.result(doc);
          swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
        } else {
          /* Async cancel form submission: */
          self.result(false);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is working without `this.result(false);`. What do you expect that to do?

Comment: @KindOfGuy This will cancel the form submission. After reading the [documentation](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) I noticed that you are able to react on user responses. Please test the code in my updated answer.

Comment: This cancels the form submission, and renders the form unusable if the user clicks cancel (button blanked out) e.g. if they want to edit their entry. User has to refresh to use at that stage. Any ideas?

Comment: @KindOfGuy Strange. You could try to call `AutoForm.resetForm(formId);` when cancelling the form submission. If you provide a repository, I'll have a look.

Comment: That doesn't work either, nor `this.resetForm();`. There are no errors on client or server either. I don't have a repo I can share at the moment :(  Any other ideas?

Comment: btw, where does `isConfirm` come from?

Comment: @KindOfGuy Without a repository it will be hard for me to reproduce the issue. However, I have updated my answer. Could you please test the code?

Comment: @KindOfGuy According to the [SweetAlert documentation](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) you can pass a parameter and check how the user responded to the confirmation.

Comment: Thank you! Was that a little bit tricky or it it just me?! What's the trick with using `var self = this;`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107784/discussion-between-kindofguy-and-matthias-eckhart).

Comment: @KindOfGuy You are welcome! Well, to be honest, I think my first proposal worked. Probably you didn't see that I used [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in order to lexically bind the `this` value. That's why I later changed to `var self = this;`.